# macOS 10.14, Xcode 9: tsan still barks even with @synchronized

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

In a old project written in Objective-C, manual retain/release, in a subclass of NSOperationQueue, I have this code:

```
- (NSError*)error {
        NSError* error;
        @synchronized(self) {
                error = m_error;  // Debugger stops here
        }
        return error;
}

- (void)setError:(NSError*)error
  operationGroup:(NSString*)operationGroup {
        error = [error errorByAddingUserInfoObject:operationGroup
                                            forKey:constKeySSYOperationGroup];

        @synchronized(self) {
                [m_error release];
                m_error = error;
                [m_error retain];
        }
}
```

You see it uses `@synchronized` to protect access to the instance variable m_error.  In spite of this, when this code runs in macOS 10.14 Mojave Beta 4 (18A336e), in Xcode 9.4.1, I sometimes get a complaint from Thread Sanitizer (tsan):

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=60795)
  Read of size 8 at 0x7b14000cc528 by thread T20:
    #0 -[SSYOperationQueue error] <null> (Bkmxwork:x86_64+0x2b3613)
    #1 -[SSYOperationQueue observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] <null> (Bkmxwork:x86_64+0x2b50d7)
    #2 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver <null> (Foundation:x86_64+0x3b08b)
    #3 _dispatch_client_callout <null> (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x44c0)

  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b14000cc528 by thread T13:
    #0 -[SSYOperationQueue setError:operationGroup:] <null> (Bkmxwork:x86_64+0x2b382a)
    #1 -[SSYOperationQueue setError:operation:] <null> (Bkmxwork:x86_64+0x2b3a80)
    #2 -[SSYOperationQueue observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] <null> (Bkmxwork:x86_64+0x2b525d)
    #3 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver <null> (Foundation:x86_64+0x3b08b)
    #4 _dispatch_client_callout <null> (libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x44c0)
```

The debugger stops at the line commented `// Debugger stops here`, indicating that there is somehow a race between those two accessors over m_error.

What might be wrong?  I've been told that tsan never raises a false alarm, and have never seen a reason to doubt it until now.  Is it possible that using last year's Xcode (9) with this year's macOS (10.14) confuses tsan?  Or has it gotten smarter as usual with the new OS?  I did not see this warning until I upgraded from macOS 10.13.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David Philip Oster for explaining the problem to me: **My getter is not atomic.**

Say that the @synchronized block of the getter executes, assigning `m_error` to `error`.  But before the getter returns, the setter is called and its @synchronized block executes, releasing m_error.  Then the getter returns a released and probably invalid m_error.

The solution is to add a retain and autorelease:

```
- (NSError*)error {
    NSError* error ;
    @synchronized(self) {
        error = [m_error retain];
    }
    return [error autorelease];
   }
```

For more on this ancient topic, see this [2009 blog post by Matt Gallagher](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html)